# How to not rerender every item in a list in React?

Tags: reactjs

I wanted create list of components that filters content. But I noticed that every time I change state of a single filter it rerenders whole list, buy it should rerender only item where `active` prop changes.

Here is [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-fermat-dqdqy) as an example of problem.

I used [why-did-you-render](https://github.com/welldone-software/why-did-you-render) package to understand why it being rerendered and it sais that it is because of `onChangeFilter`.

How is it possible to optimize render? And why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this update would impact the performance, but if you really want to:

wrap Filter with a `memo`:

```
const Filter = memo(({ children, id, active, onChange }) => {
```

and onChangeFilter with a `useCallback` and an empty array as the 2nd parameter:

```
const onChangeFilter = useCallback(id => {
...
}, [])
```

this way you are recreating the reference for onChangeFilter every time.

https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-sunset-6yd17